# How to set environment variable in the .Net Core app which is automated deployed with Teamcity

Tags: azure, configuration, continuous-integration, teamcity, .net-core

I have configured continuous integration (BitBucket) of my `.Net Core` app to `Azure/IIS` using `Teamcity`. I am following this [article](https://medium.com/monkii/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-sites-using-teamcity-or-just-command-line-cf05fdee58f5).

Now my continuous integration is happening properly and app is deployed to `Azure` correctly whenever I check in any changes to Bitbucket repo.

The problem is, environment variable of my .Net Core app is by default set to `Production`.

I know we can set environment variable using command:

```
set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Development"
```

But I wonder, how I can specify this setting in my Teamcity build?

Comment: hosted as what ? web app or container ?

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the linked article you can find an update and another link to the [`TeamCity` team blog article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/teamcity-dotnet-core/), where you can find a way to set up the environment variable:

> If you want to tune some parameters in your build steps, the `.NET Core` plugin provides details about configuration options and hints at their possible values

So you need to select `Runner type` equal to `.Net Core (dotnet)`, and `Configuration` equal to `Development`:

[image]